# Wordpress: Pretty Permalink Breaks sidebar PHP

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, break, sidebar

I'm updating a legacy site for a client. It was a very old wordpress from 2009. A lot of the code is mixed with static and dynamic.

The sidebar changes with different pages depending on the page template.

This is the current side bar code

```
<div id="sidebar">
<?php 
    $pageID = $_GET["page_id"];
    $sidebar = get_post_meta($pageID, 'sidebar', true);

    if(is_single()){
        $sidebar = 'Blog';
    }

    if(!dynamic_sidebar($sidebar)){
    echo "Could not find sidebar";
  }

?>
</div>
```

When I change the permalinks to prettypermalinks it breaks the sidebar and get this error "Could not find sidebar"

When I change the permalinks back to default it works again.

Does anyone have any idea of the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the $_GET request that is specifically looking for the page ID instead of something like the slug, or whatever is in the query string after you updated the permalinks.

Try this instead.

```
<div id="sidebar">
<?php 
    $pageID = get_the_ID();
    $sidebar = get_post_meta($pageID, 'sidebar', true);

    if(is_single()){
        $sidebar = 'Blog';
    }

    if(!dynamic_sidebar($sidebar)){
    echo "Could not find sidebar";
  }

?>
</div>
```

Also for future reference, the "Could not find sidebar" message is not really an "error" - It's just the output you're getting from the last "if".